How do photons travel through time?
I was watching a video, and in this video they used a chart to explain time dilation. Basically, when you travel through space, it slows down your speed through time, since time is a dimension, and the sum of all your dimensional velocities has to equal the speed of light.
However, this got me thinking. If you have any speed less than the speed of light, you are still traveling through time. But the second you hit the speed of light, time should just stop. That is because if your spatial velocities sum to c, then your velocity through time has to be 0. I’m not talking about how a massless entity traveling at the speed of light would experience time, I’m asking about how outside observers do in our current view of physics. If something is traveling at light speed, it doesn’t matter how much time dilation it experiences, it will literally never progress through time. So how do photons do just that?

What this all means is that there is no inertial frame where light is at rest, that makes sense to use for describing sub-lightspeed events. You are trying to envision what it "looks like to be a photon" but 1) everyone who has studied relativity has had that thought, and 2) it leads nowhere :)

You have a misconception, photons obviously change position, so they move through space. You are talking about the four velocity, not the coordinate velocity, there are some technicalities that make your statement inaccurate.

I’m not talking about perspective. It poses no problems that light cannot experience time. But is it not the case that something’s four-velocity cannot surpass the speed of light? So either they don’t move at the speed of light, or they don’t travel through time. What about that is incorrect?

This might help - How does a photon experience space and time?

Not sure this isn’t mainstream physics. At the very least this is closed for the wrong reason.

@controlgroup I changed it and got rid of the part suggesting that photons might be massless, then told them about that, but they still won’t reopen it.

I don’t know why. If I had the rep to cast reopen votes, I would.

You’re fundamentally right: an object moving at exactly $c$ does not experience proper time. In the limit as $v\to c$, time dilation is infinite (so an external observer sees their clocks as having stopped), and the lightspeed photon sees all points in the Universe as having zero distance from one another (ignoring spacetime deformities). In other words, photons follow null curves, curves with that property you note where the four-velocity’s components are only spatial.
The key thing is that time dilation and length contraction go hand in hand here. The photon experiences no time, but from the photon’s point of view, it doesn’t cross any distance either. Normally this kind of thing isn’t allowed, but because the photon has no mass it (and other massless particles) can zoom along null curves without breaking anything.
If the photon did have mass, we’d also note that electromagnetism (and thus light) would have a finite range: massless force carriers lead to infinite-range forces for the reason that force-carrying particles are limited in lifetime proportional to their mass (hence the weak force, with heavy W and Z bosons carrying it, is very short-range, whereas massless-carrier-particle gravity and electromagnetism are infinite range). Since we’ve observed that electromagnetism and light extend across the entire Universe regardless of range, we know that the photon must be massless (or at least have a mass far too small to measure).

Nice answer (+1) I think what the proper time business is doing is really measuring frequency of e.g. a Caesium atom clock? As something speeds up, the clock ticks less for some reason. When something reaches light speed, the clock supposedly ceases to "tick" at all. This is why proper time reads zero. Clearly though the photon is moving in time (changing location in space at different time points) despite what its clock is reading. If the photon truly does not "experience time", this means the photon would be present everywhere all at once, which is not what we observe, right?

Well… here’s a question, how do you track where a photon is at any given time? It doesn’t scatter other photons; can’t you only really tell where it is when it hits your eye/a detector? From a relativistic standpoint they sort of do exist everywhere on their world line at the same time for that exact reason. It might appear to be moving through time because its position might change as you see it if you could predetermine its path, but if you were sitting on the photon you would perceive travelling a distance of any length as instantaneous.

That’s what is really meant by not experiencing time - an observer moving at $c$ can cross an arbitrarily-large distance in zero proper time because time dilation is infinite/length contraction is zero, so either way you look at it the journey (according to the observer) is instantaneous.

Thank you, you mean the "wavefunction" of the photon can collapse anywhere along the worldline due to zero proper time, right? Suppose we send a photon towards Alpha Centauri now, then is it possible that this photon will collapse at a location in Alpha Centauri 1 minute later, if it's wavefunction is diffuse enough and non-zero at Alpha Centauri?

Theoretically yes the photon's wavefunction can collapse into a state that leads it anywhere in the Universe (a Gaussian probability distribution is everywhere nonzero), but in order to cause the collapse you'd need to do an observation of the photon's position at Centauri which would require going there in the first place. Plus the probability of observing a photon that far away from its approximate position is virtually nil.

But… how? Say you have a person flying a spaceship to Alpha Centauri, who has a caesium clock connected to a computer that uses speed to adjust for time dilation. Then say that they send a signal to earth and then wait for it to arrive before recording when they receive the light. Then they come back to earth, and scientists compare when the signal was sent/recieved. It couldn’t ever received until after 4.2465 years, could it?

The point I was trying to make is that the probability that the photon could be observed to be somewhere farther away than possible isn’t zero but it’s so astronomically unlikely that it would never be observed (like proton decay). Above the quantum scale you can ignore those kinds of effects, and the quantum scale is many dozens of orders of magnitude smaller than the kind of scales we’re talking about…
